# Cannot cast object error while invoke web service method

Tags: java, web-services, groovy

I was trying to consume a web service [http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertSpeed.asmx?WSDL]
 and invoke a method in it.

It has only one method called SpeedUnit and trying use it with customized parameter.

It works only if I give like the below code

```
double res = serProxy.convertSpeed(spd,SpeedUnit.milesPerhour,
            SpeedUnit.kilometersPerhour);
```

But I want to manage the 2nd and 3rd parameter like the below.

```
    double spd = 100;  
    SpeedUnit callTunit = "SpeedUnit."+toUnit;
    SpeedUnit callFunit = "SpeedUnit."+fromUnit;
    double res = serProxy.convertSpeed(spd,callFunit,
            callTunit);
```

I get below cast exception error message

"Cannot cast object 'SpeedUnit.kilometersPerhour' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'NET.webserviceX.www.SpeedUnit' "

In SpeedUnit class those objects are declared as like the below.

```
public class SpeedUnit implements java.io.Serializable {
private java.lang.String _value_;
private static java.util.HashMap _table_ = new java.util.HashMap();protected SpeedUnit(java.lang.String value) {
    _value_ = value;
    _table_.put(_value_,this);
}
public static final java.lang.String _milesPerhour = "milesPerhour";
public static final java.lang.String _kilometersPerhour = "kilometersPerhour";
public static final SpeedUnit milesPerhour = new SpeedUnit(_milesPerhour);
public static final SpeedUnit kilometersPerhour = new SpeedUnit(_kilometersPerhour);
```

Help from any one is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Madhan

Comment: What is `toUnit` and `fromUnit` datatype? Are they Strings? Please give the real values as well.

Comment: toUnit and fromUnit are String datatype and it holds values  milesPerhour and kilometersPerhour respectivley

Comment: I have posted an answer. Please check if that helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to pass a new instance of `SpeedUnit` based upon the values of `toUnit` and `fromUnit`. I totally assume that `toUnit` and `fromUnit` are `String` datatype since you have done the concatenation. If my assumption is correct, you can change the code to

```
SpeedUnit fromSUUnit = null;
SpeedUnit toSUUnit = null;
if(fromUnit !=null && fromUnit.equals("milesPerhour"))
fromSUUnit = SpeedUnit.milesPerhour;
if(toUnit !=null && toUnit.equals("kilometersPerhour"))
toSUUnit = SpeedUnit.kilometersPerhour;
double res = serProxy.convertSpeed(spd,fromSUUnit,toSUUnit);
```

Hope this clarifies.

Disclaimer : The code above is not tested. Just typed it though to provide the logic

Answer (score 0):

webservice contains string value and you are sending a SpeedUnit object to the webservice. Just pass the string value as it is. serProxy.convertSpeed(spd,toUnit,
            fromUnit);

Comment: I changed like as you said and I got error NoMethod Exception

Comment: Error Message: ` No signature of method: NET.webserviceX.www.ConvertSpeedsSoapProxy.convertSpeed() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Double, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [100.0, SpeedUnit.kilometersPerhour, SpeedUnit.milesPerhour]`